# Matrix algebra with unknown value in R

Tags: r, matrix, algebra

There is a way to solve matrix algebra in R, like it's possible to do in the site:
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-calculator

I'm trying to solve this on R:
[image with aexample of what i'm trying to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LYxt.png)

I have also tried to use the package ktsolve, but i think it can't do what i want.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your goals, optimization may be the fastest and easiest alternative like in

```
calculate <- function(x){
    A <- matrix(c(1 ,2 ,x), nrow = 1)
    B <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1), nrow = 3)
    C <- matrix(c(1, 2, x), nrow = 3)
    return(abs(A %*% B %*% C - 1))
}


optimize(calculate, c(-100, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried your code and that have done what i want. Do you know where can i learn more about this kind of problems?

Comment: The `optimize` function and it's brother `optim` do not do matrix algebra  -  they just search for minima and maxima in arbitrary functions through iterations. 
If you do not need this formally solved but just good solutions, you can do a lot just by reading `help(optimize)` and `help(optim)`. Then you can read a lot more here: https://www.is.uni-freiburg.de/ressourcen/computational-economics/5_OptimizationR.pdf There also is a TaskView on optimization https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html  If this does what you wanted, you might consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank you. You give me a lot of new info for me. The slides are very helpful. You help me a lot.

Comment: You could express the thanks by accepting the answer or at least upvote it.

Comment: I forgot to do it, but I will accept the answer right now. I tried to upvote but i have this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."